# iOS Beginner: Tweet calculated result (HowTo add a result to a NSString and tweet it)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, twitter

I am trying to integrate twitter framework into my app to give the users the option
to tweet their calculated results. Tweeting works fine but I'm unable to get the results
to the Twitter window automatically.

1. User enters played holes and strokes needed on the golf course.
2. App calculates average strokes per hole.
3. After clicking on tweet results button twitter window appears and has already 
   the calculated average as a part of the twitter message.

Right now the Twitter window shows up but I can only assign static text as default.

Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

CALCULATION: (works fine)

```
- (IBAction)calculateNow:(id)sender {

    double holes = [[holesTextField text]doubleValue];
    double strokes = [[strokesTextField text]doubleValue];
    double result = strokes / holes;
    [averageTextField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", result]];
}
```

TWITTER: (works but window does not include the calculated average)

```
- (IBAction)tweetMyAverage:(id)sender {
    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc]init];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Average is: %@", result]];
        [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I think that the variable result (from the calculation) is not 
known in the twitter IBAction but how can I make it available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an variable to your .h file in the `@interface` section:

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController {

    double result; 

}

@end
```

Then it will be available to use in your .m in every method.

Remove the `double` class from the instance variable you create in the `calculateNow` method to make sure you don't get a warning as you are creating a separate variable.

```
result = strokes / holes;
```

Also, make sure that you use `%d` for doubles, `%@` is for strings.

```
[tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Average is: %d", result]];
```

Comment: You guys rock! Thanks a lot for correcting my code and explainin what I have done wrong. It works now. Love this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the code you supplied is in the same view controller, you can do this:

```
     [tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Average is: %@",
     averageTextField.text]];
```

Comment: Yes sir, all code supplied is in the same view controller. Thank you too! have a nice day.

Comment: Looks like I can only flag one respond as accepted answer but both suggestions work.

Comment: @marc - glad to help.  Btw, when you get more rep points later, you could come back and upvote this answer.  I wouldn't mind :-)